# ActiveAdmin : How to Filter data from resource. Note: not the search filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I am using activeadmin for creating admin module of an application(Ruby on Rail 4.2 App). I have a model car which will be validated from admin side. One thing that i don't understand is that how can i filter data from model. You may consider following as what i am trying to do.

Assume there are 10 records in your model/table for cars say '**car**' with a special field/attribute '**car_type**' which can take values only from

01 - hatchback

02 - sports_car

03 - sedan

04 - van

How can i show only records with **car_type** as **van**

My *car.rb* file for model user at dashboard :

```
ActiveAdmin.register Car do

filter :model_name
filter :model_number


index do
    column :model_name
    column :model_number
    actions defaults: false do |user|
      (link_to 'Sell', "/some route").html_safe
    end 
end
```

end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Index Scopes` of active admin

```
ActiveAdmin.register Car do

  filter :model_name
  filter :model_number

  scope :all, default: true
  scope("Hatchback") { |scope| scope.where(car_type: "hatchback") }
  scope("Sports Car") { |scope| scope.where(car_type: "sports_car") }
  scope("Sedan") { |scope| scope.where(car_type: "sedan") }
  scope("Van") { |scope| scope.where(car_type: "van") }

  index do
    column :model_name
    column :model_number
    actions defaults: false do |user|
      (link_to 'Sell', "/some route").html_safe
  end 
end
```

Index Scopes will show filter at the top of index with following options

- all
- Hathchback
- Sports Car
- Sedan
- Van

all will be selected by default - if you want to set Van to be by default

```
 scope("Van") { |scope| scope.where(car_type: "van") }, default: true
```

[Customizing the Active Admin Index Page](http://activeadmin.info/docs/3-index-pages.html)

Comment: it is partially correct. I tried making this scope as my default scope. But it throws an error :       syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end

Comment: this is how custom scope is defined as default :                              scope("Instructors", default: true)  { |scope| scope.where(:instructor => [2])}